# Border-right and border-left height not matching the padding on element HTML-CSS

Tags: html, css, flexbox, border

```css
:root {
  --gray: #CBC4C4;
  --blue: #029DF1;
  --white: #FFF;
  --black: #000;
  --secondBlue: #0089D3;
}

* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  font-family: Roboto, sans-serif;
  color: var(--white);
}

#container {
  margin: 100px auto;
  background-color: var(--blue);
  width: 300px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 10px 0px;
}

p, i {
  margin-right: 50px;
}

i {
  border-left: 1px solid var(--gray);
  border-right: 1px solid var(--gray);
  padding: 0px 20px;
  height: inherit;
  color: var(--black);
}

i:hover {
  background-color: var(--secondBlue);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/1f5460a8a6.js"></script>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <title>Stopwatch</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="container">
    <p id="timeArea">Blank</p>
    <!-- <i id="pauseButton" class="fas fa-pause fa-2x"></i> -->
    <i id="playButton" class="fas fa-play fa-2x"></i>
    <p id="reset">Reset</p>
  </div>
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

I am wanting to matching the height of the borders to the amount of padding I have set for my i element. Here is a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/utoqjd13/) visualizing how it looks.

What I have done so far is set the height to 100%, given the container div and i element a box-sizing: border-box property, but they have not worked. How can I proceed?

Comment: I'm not quite sure what your question is, please explain more.

Comment: The borders only go as high as the element, not the element and padding I've added. I'm trying to make the borders hit reach the point where the #container's padding top and bottom end.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To be specific to your answer,

1. Remove `padding` from `container`
2. Assign `padding` to `i`

```css
:root {
  --gray: #CBC4C4;
  --blue: #029DF1;
  --white: #FFF;
  --black: #000;
  --secondBlue: #0089D3;
}

* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  font-family: Roboto, sans-serif;
  color: var(--white);
}


/*REMOVED FROM HERE*/

#container {
  margin: 100px auto;
  background-color: var(--blue);
  width: 300px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

p,
i {
  margin-right: 50px;
}


/*ADDED HERE*/

i {
  border-left: 1px solid var(--gray);
  border-right: 1px solid var(--gray);
  padding: 20px;
  height: inherit;
  color: var(--black);
}

i:hover {
  background-color: var(--secondBlue);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/1f5460a8a6.js"></script>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <title>Stopwatch</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="container">
    <p id="timeArea">Blank</p>
    <!-- <i id="pauseButton" class="fas fa-pause fa-2x"></i> -->
    <i id="playButton" class="fas fa-play fa-2x"></i>
    <p id="reset">Reset</p>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

```css
:root {
  --gray: #CBC4C4;
  --blue: #029DF1;
  --white: #FFF;
  --black: #000;
  --secondBlue: #0089D3;
}

* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  font-family: Roboto, sans-serif;
  color: var(--white);
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  background: royalblue;
  width: 300px;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  margin: auto;
}

.box {
  display: flex;
  padding: 10px;
  flex: 1;
  justify-content: center;
}

.playButton {
  border-left: 2px solid white;
  border-right: 2px solid white;
}

.playButton:hover {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/1f5460a8a6.js"></script>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <title>Stopwatch</title>
</head>

<body>

  <div class="container">
    <div class="box">
      <p>Blank</p>
    </div>
    <div class="playButton box">
      <i id="playButton" class="fas fa-play fa-2x"></i>
    </div>
    <div class="box">
      <p>Reset</p>
    </div>
  </div>

  <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to remove the padding from the `#container` `div` and place the `10px` top and bottom padding to your `i` element otherwise your left and right border height will always be less than the `#container` `div`.

```css
:root {
  --gray: #CBC4C4;
  --blue: #029DF1;
  --white: #FFF;
  --black: #000;
  --secondBlue: #0089D3;
}

* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  font-family: Roboto, sans-serif;
  color: var(--white);
}

#container {
  margin: 100px auto;
  background-color: var(--blue);
  width: 300px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

p, i {
  margin-right: 50px;
}

i {
  border-left: 1px solid var(--gray);
  border-right: 1px solid var(--gray);
  padding: 10px 20px;
  height: inherit;
  color: var(--black);
}

i:hover {
  background-color: var(--secondBlue);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/1f5460a8a6.js"></script>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <title>Stopwatch</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="container">
    <p id="timeArea">Blank</p>
    <!-- <i id="pauseButton" class="fas fa-pause fa-2x"></i> -->
    <i id="playButton" class="fas fa-play fa-2x"></i>
    <p id="reset">Reset</p>
  </div>
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```